Does R limit computations to a single core? Can it?
It's been a while so my memory is hazy, but I recall that when I used Matlab on HPC, I had to explicitly tell Matlab not to use more threads than my job requested, otherwise Matlab would eat into the resources of other jobs on the node (not sure if this is still the case).
From man R, I don't see any relevant arguments. I did a quick search and the gist I got is that R itself is single threaded, but packages may not be. So I think my questions are:

On the HPC, is R going to run all computations exclusively on a single thread, unless I explicitly ask it to use additional threads (i.e., via specialized packages)?
Are there any command line arguments to enforce this?

Just trying to be a conscientious HPC-citizen.

Yes, R is single-threaded unless you use specialized packages to make it otherwise.

Do be aware that some packages (e.g. data.table) will run multi-threaded code without having to explicitly opt in.

In that case @Axeman, it seems like I would want to limit R to a certain number of threads, to be on the safe side. Do you know if this is possible?

Assuming your HPC is some Linux flavour yes there are various ways to do this such as taskset or numactl. See e.g.  here. Are you sure you need to though? Seems a strange setup to rely on conscientious users. I would consult with your sys admin about this.

Depending on the package, you may be able to set the number of threads inside R, e.g. setDTthreads() for data.table. What software package/s are you using?

Also consider whether the node is using a multi threaded BLAS like OPENBLAS-OPENMP. Depending on ncpu settings, it may significantly affect performance if all users use many cores at each vector/matrix operation. Consider setting ncpu wisely or use a fast single-threaded alternative like OPENBLAS-SERIAL. Alternatively there's  RhpcBLASctl::blas_set_num_threads() which probably only makes sense if all users use it, however.

According this article, you can explicitly specify the number of threads to use via the RhpcBLASctl library
